# backgroundTint property colores the whole TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, line

I want to set color just for  editText underline. how can I achieve it ? as I mention in title, I tried to set backgroundTint property, but instead of coloring underline, the whole TextInputEditText is being colored

xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="384dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameInputLayout"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="#8E8E93">
    
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:text="@={authViewModel._password}"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `backgroundTint` property, try the following code (which will enable you to set the underline color of the `TextInputEditText` and from then on you can customize it to your liking:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/textInputLayout.BlueLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            style="@style/textInputLayout.BlueLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="textInputLayout.BlueLabel"
        parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance"
        parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/teal_200</item> <!--Change underline color here-->
    </style>
</resources>
```

As you can see now, we have changed the underline color to a tealish-bluish color:

[image]

[image]

The only *caveat* is that the appearance of the `TextInputLayout` is not really 'material-like'. If you run into any bugs or issues let me know in the comments.